# Webcal/WebDev integration in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, webcal

I am trying to provide a webcal link to my registered user like below

webcal://www.domain.com/ical/get_event?uid=13301632&key=asdgagaweg

in a Ruby on Rails app so he can load the event entries in his calender application (Outlook, Ical). I have looked into both RiCal and icalendar but neither show any support for providing URL.

How should I go about creating my own Webcal URL? What are all the steps I have to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Is the end-point a file (e.g. ical file) or a server? If the former you simply need to generate the proper .ics file and serve it up, e.g. with HTTP. If the latter then you need a WebCal server (see http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/servers.html or write your own [e.g. using Milton -- milton.io]).